# Yii2: Modal update form from link on every row in GridView

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have a GridView that displays rows from a related model.
I've managed to put a link on every row that takes to the update form of the related model. But I need that also on clicking on that link the update form is displayed on a modal popup window.
This is what I got in my GridView, the column I need with modal:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'columns' => [
    [
        'label' => 'Spraying',
        'format' => 'raw',
        'value' => function ($model, $key, $index) {
            return Html::a($model->numero_spraying, ['spraying/'.'update', 'id' => $model->id_spraying]);
        },
    ],
```

This is how it looks now:
[GridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yKyV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this provides the basic structure for your requirement

```
<?php
    yii\bootstrap\Modal::begin([
    'headerOptions' => ['id' => 'modalHeader'],
    'id' => 'modal',
    'size' => 'modal-lg',
    'clientOptions' => ['backdrop' => 'static', 'keyboard' => FALSE]
    ]);
?>
    <div id='modalContent'></div>;
<?php yii\bootstrap\Modal::end();?>
```

the above code Will populate a bootstrap model widget

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'id'=>'need-model',
    'columns' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Spraying',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model, $key, $index) {
                return Html::a($model->numero_spraying, ['spraying/'.'update'],
                ,['class'=>"update-dialog","data-form-id"=>$model->id_spraying]
                );
            },
        ],

    ],
]); ?>
```

The above code will register a class for every link .here i have deligated every click with

```
<?php


$this->registerJs('$("#modal").delegate(".update-dialog","click",function(event){ \
    id = $(this)->attr("data-form-id");
    //load ajax and show model \
    $.post( "'.Url::toRoute("your/action").'", {id:id}, function( data ) {\
      $("#modal").find("#modalContent").html( data ).modal("show");\
    });\
});');?>
```

Comment: Thank you Midhun, if it's not asking too much, could you elaborate on the load ajax and show model part please?. I've never used ajax on Yii so I'm lost on that part.

Comment: Thanks @Midhun, I'm putting the registerJs code inside the column tag of the GridView, after the value function, is that correct? Regards.

Comment: No write the register js after the grid view

Comment: What does the ' after the registerJs and the \ at the end of line 1?. I'm putting that block where you said (after closing the GridView) and it's giving some errors: unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'

Comment: sorry i have fixed the code 
i was typing that in a hurry :)

Comment: Thanks, the error disappears, now I'm getting "bad request #400, required parameter id missing", I think somehow the ID of the row is not passing to the Url::toRoute. But if I inspect the element the "data-form-id" gets the right ID.

Comment: No, at clicking the link shows "bad request #400, required parameter id missing" on a normal window, no popup.

Comment: is the issue fixed ?